# Function that assigns a category to different percentage orders

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am new to R and have written a function that iterates over a dataframe and assigns a category to each row in the dataframe based on the percentage of each category. The syntax works but it returns all NA values. Some help would be much appreciated!

```
glimpse(age_aggrevated)
Rows: 19,751
Columns: 4
$ x_perc     <dbl> 0.06159420, 0.09665427, 0.11051213, 0.06236080, 0.12429379, 0.08370044, 0.09742120, 0.05893536, 0.07514451, 0~
$ y_perc     <dbl> 0.4601449, 0.4200743, 0.4393531, 0.3763920, 0.4491525, 0.4493392, 0.4469914, 0.4581749, 0.5722543, 0.4589474,~
$ z_perc     <dbl> 0.39855072, 0.46096654, 0.39353100, 0.53452116, 0.40960452, 0.44933921, 0.46991404, 0.43346008, 0.25144509, 0~
$ SA1_CODE21 <chr> "10102100701", "10102100702", "10102100703", "10102100704", "10102100705", "10102100706", "10102100707", "101~
```

```
age_aggrevated$age_cat <- vector(mode="character", length = nrow(age_aggrevated))

assignCategory <- function(x_perc, y_perc, z_perc, category) {
  for(i in 1:length(age_aggrevated)) {
    if((x_perc[i] > y_perc[i] & x_perc[i] > z_perc[i]) & y_perc[i] > z_perc[i]) {
      category[i] == "A"
    }
    else if((x_perc[i] > y_perc[i] & x_perc[i] > z_perc[i]) & z_perc[i] > y_perc[i]){
      category[i] == "B"
    }
    else if((y_perc[i] > x_perc[i] & y_perc[i] > z_perc[i]) & x_perc[i] > z_perc[i]){
      category[i] == "C"
    }
    else if((y_perc[i] > x_perc[i] & y_perc[i] > z_perc[i]) & z_perc[i] > x_perc[i]){
      category[i] == "D"
    }
    else if((z_perc[i] > x_perc[i] & z_perc[i] > y_perc[i]) & x_perc[i] > y_perc[i]){
      category[i] == "E"
    }
    else if((z_perc[i] > x_perc[i] & z_perc[i] > y_perc[i]) & y_perc[i] > x_perc[i]){
      category[i] == "F"
    }
    else if ((x_perc[i] == 0.000) & (y_perc[i] == 0.000) & (z_perc[i] == 0.000)){
      category[i] = NA
    }
  }
  return(category)
}

age_aggrevated$age_cat <- assignCategory(age_aggrevated$x_perc, age_aggrevated$y_perc, age_aggrevated$z_perc, age_aggrevated$age_cat)
```

The structure of the value "category"

```
str(category)
 logi [1:19737] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: This can likely be accomplished using dplyr's `case_when` function. Using the vectorized approach will speed up the code too!

Comment: Note that all your assignments use `==` this is used for checking equality, not for assignment. Replace the `==` with `=` or `<-`. For example: `category[i] == "F"` becomes `category[i] <- "F"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# Create 10 rows of fake data
test_df <- tibble(x = runif(10),
                  y = runif(10),
                  z = runif(10))

categorized_df <- test_df |> 
  mutate(category = case_when(x >= y & y >= z          ~ "A",
                              x >= y & x >= z & z >= y ~ "B",
                              y >= x & x >= z          ~ "C",
                              y >= x & y >= z & z >= x ~ "D",
                              z >= x & x >= y          ~ "E",
                              z >= x & z >= y & y >= x ~ "F",
                              # The default value for case_when is NA
                              # but we'll manually put this in anyway
                              x == 0 & y == 0 & z == 0 ~ NA_character_
                              ))

categorized_df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>         x     y      z category
#>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 0.266  0.206 0.935  E       
#>  2 0.372  0.177 0.212  B       
#>  3 0.573  0.687 0.652  D       
#>  4 0.908  0.384 0.126  A       
#>  5 0.202  0.770 0.267  D       
#>  6 0.898  0.498 0.386  A       
#>  7 0.945  0.718 0.0134 A       
#>  8 0.661  0.992 0.382  C       
#>  9 0.629  0.380 0.870  E       
#> 10 0.0618 0.777 0.340  D
```